# ESLint no-use-before-define

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How do I get this ESLint rule (`no-use-before-define`) to not warn in cases like these;

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() { return <div>{messages.helloWorld}</div> }
}

const messages = { helloWorld: 'Hello world!' }
```

This is a simplified example, but I'd really like to have `messages` defined at the bottom of each component's file (by convention).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It looks like you might be interested in the `variables` option, for this rule. You can read about that option [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define#options).

> This flag determines whether or not the rule checks variable declarations in upper scopes. If this is true, the rule warns every reference to a variable before the variable declaration. Otherwise, the rule ignores a reference if the declaration is in an upper scope, while still reporting the reference if it's in the same scope as the declaration.

You might configure it, in your `.eslintrc`, [like so](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define#variables) ...

```
{
  "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "variables": false }]
}
```

This will keep that rule enabled for other things, such as classes and functions and variables in the same scope, but will relax it for variables in upper scopes.

Comment: Is there a way to mark "variables" as "warn" instead of relaxing the rule?

Comment: Actually, having this rule turned on for functions doesn't make any sense - they ARE hoisted, while classes and variables are not. Like I said in a comment below, turning this rule globally just make linter skip really bad cases of accessing variables before they're defined.

Comment: The problem with "variables":false is that it won't catch immediate executions. Eg. this is correct code `const getB = () => b; const b = 'B';`, so we might be tempted to relax the eslint for variables. But this is incorrect: `const b2 = (() => b)(); const b = 'B';` and it will be ignored by eslint with "variables":false, leading to error during runtime.

Answer (score 11):

#### Rule disabled for function and classes declarations

```
"rules": {    
  "no-use-before-define": ["error", {"functions": false, "classes": false}]
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because functions and classes are going to be hoisted in runtime and it fills silly to apply this rule for those

Answer (score 3):

Before the `render` line, do this:

`// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define`

See the [eslint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments).

Comment: I don't think he really wants to do that in every of the files he has. Your solution works but is partial. I am not saying it's not useful sometimes, but I guess a more general answer is better.

Comment: The problem with this rule turned off globally is that now even really nasty errors like `const storedData = await fetchStoredData(); const data = storedData ? JSON.parse(data) : null;` look innocent to your linter. So I don't think it's a good idea turning this off globally.